# Spring Boot / Spring Security role based authorization not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to learn Spring Security with Spring Boot. I have a demo where I am implementing it. It works fine with login page and profile method which can be authenticate by any valid user. But when I am trying to access for a specific role then it does not work and gives me a "403 - access denied".

My access point >>

```
    @Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "/home.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/profile")
    public String profile() {
        return "/profile.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String admin() {
        return "/admin.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/management")
    public String management() {
        return "/management.jsp";
    }

}
```

My configure method >>

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/management").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGEMENT")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();
}
```

My role assigned >>

```
    @Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the most unobvious thing about Spring Security. Roles and authorities are the same things but roles should be prefixed with `ROLE_`. So, the correct usage is

```java
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
}
```